# background-color fills another tag | CSS

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a simple html page with some basic css.
For some reason banner overrides the ul with his background-color.

http://jsfiddle.net/NmRAB/

```
 <ul>
    <li>
        <h1>veediback</h1>
    </li>
    <li>Groups</li>
    <li>Discover</li>
</ul>
<div id="banner"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
h1 {
    font-style: italic;
    display: inline;
    color:#3366FF;
}
li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
ol, ul {
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin-left:20vw;
}
#banner {
    height:30%;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: You haven't set a background colour on the `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due the `float: left;` which removes all the `<li>` elements from the flow of the web and leaves your `<ul>` with 0px height.

What you want to do is to clear the `.banner`, by applying `clear:left;` or `clear: both;`

Answer (score 1):

The ul is still there, you just can't see it, because it is also black. You have to change the color of the list items, or the background.
And if you want the banner to appear after the list, you should get rid of the "float: left;" of "ol, ul".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **[link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/NmRAB/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@chris, UL is `float:left` in your css which is overriding banner div. Try using `clear:both` in banner.

Comment: What do you mean by `overriding banner div` ??

Comment: It was coming over UL because of float css.